# How to Read CSV, Create a QR Code, and Write its Filename to New Column?

Tags: python, csv, qr-code

I'm writing a Python script to generate a QR code from the first column in a csv (concatenated with a local name), and that part works well. The csv just has three columns and looks like this:

```
ID    First    Last
144   Jerry    Seinfeld
491   George   Costanza
104   Elaine   Benes
99    Cosmo    Kramer
```

And I use my Python script to take that file, append a prefix to the `ID`s (in this case, '`NBC`') and then create QR codes for each record in a new folder. It's a little long but all of this seems to work fine also:

```
import csv
import qrcode
import os
import shutil
import time
import inquirer

#Identify Timestamp
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

local = 'NBC'

#Load csv
filename = "stackoverflowtest.csv"

#Path to new local folder
localfolder = local
localimagefolder = localfolder+'/image'
localfilefolder = localfolder+'/files'

#Check/create folders based on local
if not os.path.exists(localfolder):
    os.makedirs(localfolder)
if not os.path.exists(localimagefolder):
    os.makedirs(localimagefolder)
if not os.path.exists(localfilefolder):
    os.makedirs(localfilefolder)

#Copy uploaded file to their local's file folder
shutil.copy2(filename, localfilefolder+'/'+local+'-'+timestr+'.csv') # complete target filename given

#Read csv and generate QR code for local+first column of csv
with open(filename, 'rU') as csvfile:
    next(csvfile, None) #skip header row
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', dialect=csv.excel_tab)

    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        labeldata = row[0] #Choose first column of data to create QR codes
        print labeldata

        qr = qrcode.QRCode(
            version=1,
            error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
            box_size=10,
            border=4,
        )

        qr.add_data(local+"-"+labeldata)
        qr.make()

        img = qr.make_image()
        img.save(localimagefolder+"/"+local+"-"+labeldata+".png".format(i)) #Save image
```

It creates the NBC folder, copies each csv file in one subfolder, and creates the QR codes for each ID (`NBC-144`,`NBC-491`,`NBC-104`,`NBC-99`) in another.

The part where I'm running into a problem is opening the csv and writing the filepath/filename back to the csv (or a copy of the csv since from what I've read, I likely can't do it to the same one). Is that possible?

The closest I've come with a script that works is appending the local name with the ID and writing that back to a column but I can't seem to figure out how to do the same with a variable, let alone a filepath/filename:

```
import csv
import os
import sys

filename = 'stackoverflowtest.csv'
newfilename = 'stackoverflowtest2.csv'
local = 'NBC'

with open(filename, 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    with open(newfilename, 'w') as g:
        writer = csv.writer(g)
        for row in reader:
            new_row = row[0:] + ['-'.join([local, row[0]])]
            writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Is it possible to write something like that within my existing script to add a column for the filepath and filename? Everything I try breaks -- especially if I attempt to do it in the same script.

---

EDIT:

This is my closest attempt that overwrote the existing file

```
f=open(newfilename,'r+')
w=csv.writer(f)
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        w.writerow([newfilename])
```

Also it's still in a separate script.

Comment: @martinueau    Hi -- did you remove Python from the title because it's better to write something like this in a different language, or is it because the tags/scripts already make it known?

Comment: [**_Should questions include “tags” in their titles?_**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) sums it up.

Comment: @martineau     Ah ok thanks. Any other help with this would be great!

Comment: Just use the pandas package. df = pandas.read_csv, df.to_csv, it will trivialize your job with little overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can't run the code in your question directly, I had to commented-out portions of it in what's below for testing, but think it does everything you wanted in one loop in one script.

```
import csv
#import qrcode
import os
import shutil
import time
#import inquirer

# Identify Timestamp
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

local = 'NBC'

# Load csv
filename = "stackoverflowtest.csv"

# Path to new local folder
localfolder = local
localimagefolder = os.path.join(localfolder, 'image')
localfilefolder = os.path.join(localfolder, 'files')

# Check/create folders based on local
if not os.path.exists(localfolder):
    os.makedirs(localfolder)
if not os.path.exists(localimagefolder):
    os.makedirs(localimagefolder)
if not os.path.exists(localfilefolder):
    os.makedirs(localfilefolder)

# Copy uploaded file to their local's file folder
target = os.path.join(localfilefolder, local+'-'+timestr+'.csv') # Target filename
#shutil.copy2(filename, target)  # Don't need to do this.

# Read csv and generate QR code for local+first column of csv
with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile, open(target, 'wb') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',', dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    next(reader)  # Skip header row.

    for row in reader:
        id, first, last = row

#        qr = qrcode.QRCode(
#            version=1,
#            error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
#            box_size=10,
#            border=4,
#        )
#
#        qr.add_data(local+"-"+id)
#        qr.make()
#
#        img = qr.make_image()
        imagepath = os.path.join(localimagefolder, local+"-"+id+".png")
#        img.save(imagepath) # Save image.
        print "saving img:", imagepath

        writer.writerow(row + [local+'-'+id, imagepath])
```

Output from sample input data:

```
144,Jerry,Seinfeld,NBC-144,NBC/image/NBC-144.png
491,George,Costanza,NBC-491,NBC/image/NBC-491.png
104,Elaine,Benes,NBC-104,NBC/image/NBC-104.png
99,Cosmo,Kramer,NBC-99,NBC/image/NBC-99.png
```

Comment: @martinuea     Thank you! I'll test it out a bit later. Also -- and this may be a separate topic altogether -- is it returning the absolute filepath? The end-game goal here as well is that I can send a folder with the QR codes and spreadsheet with the filenames to someone and they can use it on their computer, even if I saved them somewhere else on mine locally.

Comment: The code uses file paths which all relative to the current-working-directory (cwd) at the time's run. The paths in the new CSV file are also relative as you can see from the sample output. You can make a copy of all files created by copying the `NBC` subdirectory along with its `image` and `files` sub-subdirectories somewhere else and the path names will still be correct, relative to its new location.